# Live video with peer to peer functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, video-streaming

At work it is requested that I make a program that can broadcast a live video via a webcam. Essentially you would use this program to name the broadcast and then start broadcasting. Another client could then search for the name of your broadcast, find it and then begin viewing the broadcast.

The second request is to save bandwidth by trying to connect to a peer to get the live broadcast. Something like a daisy chain effect. If a current peers connection is too slow then the client would try to find another peer.

Is there something already out there that I can use in my application so I don't have to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Flash 10.1 supports P2P video.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/p2p_rtmfp_groups.html

> Using the capabilities of groups and the new features around them, you can make deployments of nearly any scale and take advantage of multiuser interactive applications for data and media. Everything from application-level video multicasting to swarming file delivery and multiuser games are within easy reach of developers, without the heavy burden being laid upon a server infrastructure.

Comment: This is a flash/actionscript solution. A good one, but I am hoping there is something available for .net.

Comment: I wonder how easy it might be to add a web browser control to the video chat app UI, then drop in a Flash video chat object?  You would then need to make sure the flash video object had its own inputs for IP address to connect to etc.  Any ideas if that's even feasible?